# React: Data won't be saved to this.state

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

So I am trying to send a get request to my node server which is responding by sending a list of objects that I wish to display on my page.
Tried many different methods, but I cant seem to find a solution. Also I am rendering via the server if that's any help.

Client Code:

```
class BookTools extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        books: []
    };
    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
    this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.updateList = this.updateList.bind(this);

    fetch('/getbooks').then(function (res) {
        return res.json();
    }).then(function (json) {
        console.log(json);
        const data = JSON.stringify(json);
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ books: data})
    });
}
```

Can't use componentDidMount since it's SSR and can't seem to get componentWillMount to work either, so i tried doing it in the constructor as suggested by another. both console.logs prints out the correct response.

I have also tried doing both `this.setState({ books: json.body })` and `this.setState({ books: json.data })` with no other result. And yes i am quite new to react as well as node/express

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2):

It’s common issue in react. When you use regular function this context won’t be available so either you need to bind it or change it to arrow function.

Also make sure the API returns data

Change

```
    fetch('/getbooks').then(function (res) {
          return res.json();
}).then(function (json) {
    console.log(json);
    const data = JSON.stringify(json);
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({ books: data})
});
```

To

```
   fetch('/getbooks') 
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(json => {
            console.log(json);
            const data = JSON.stringify(json);
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({ books: data})
   });
```

Or

```
   fetch('/getbooks')
     .then(function (res) {
         return res.json();
      }.bind(this))
     .then(function (json) {
           console.log(json);
           const data = JSON.stringify(json);
           console.log(data);
           this.setState({ books: data})
   }.bind(this));
```

Comment: When i changed the code i got `Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to this.state directly or define a state = {}; class property with the desired state in the BookTools component.` which is also quite common for me, haha

Comment: What do you mean by SSR? You are not recommended to make api call in constructor. Constructor is basically for initializing state and do function bindings.

Comment: Server Side Rendering

Comment: Tried both solutions and still got the same warning :(

Comment: I know, but since i am rendering via server i can't use stuff like componentDidMount etc.. So i was suggested to do it this way :S